# Pandas: Add new dataframe column based on the dates of other smaller dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this ([link to csv](https://pastebin.com/raw/e0LZfec3)):

```
time  ,  value
 0    ,   10
 1    ,   20
 2    ,   35
 3    ,   30
 4    ,   40
 5    ,   40
 6    ,   60
```

And I want to fill another column `recentActive` based on the values from this smaller dataframe ([link to csv](https://pastebin.com/raw/5MPtGQ5X)):

```
time  ,  value , activatedTime , deactivatedTime
 1    ,   20   ,      1        ,       5
 3    ,   30   ,      3        ,       4
```

In the `recentActive` column we should have the the most recent activated value that has not been deactivated yet. Once a value is deactivated, then we should fill it with the previous still active value. The final dataframe should look like this:

```
time  ,  value  ,  recentActive
 0    ,   10    ,      NaN
 1    ,   20    ,      20   (t=1 activated)
 2    ,   30    ,      20
 3    ,   30    ,      30   (t=3 activated)
 4    ,   40    ,      30   (t=3 deactivated)
 5    ,   40    ,      20   (t=1 deactivated)
 6    ,   60    ,      NaN  (no active values)
```

How can I do this? Preferably just using vectorized operations, thanks!

Comment: how big are each dataframe in real-life?

Comment: The bigger one will have around 15000 lines and the smaller one around 500

Comment: @mozway any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: See a suggestion below, It might not be bullet-proof, don't hesitate to provide feedback with example if you have cases for which it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit complex to achieve if you want a performant solution.

You can build an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html), including a "catch-all" interval (min-max, else the slicing will fail on missing values), then slice and aggregate the potential multiple intervals matches with [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) to keep only the first one per initial value.

This assumes `df1` and `df2` as inputs and requires `df2` to be sorted on `activatedTime`.

```
import numpy as np

idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(np.r_[df1['time'].min(), df2['activatedTime']],
                                   np.r_[df1['time'].max(), df2['deactivatedTime']],
                                   closed='both')
intervals = pd.Series(np.r_[np.nan, df2['value']]).set_axis(idx)

s = intervals.loc[df1['time']]
# make groups if intervals are increasing
group = s.index.left.to_series().diff().le(0).cumsum()
df1['recentActive'] = s.groupby(group.to_numpy()).last()
```

Output:

```
   time  value  recentActive
0     0     10           NaN
1     1     20          20.0
2     2     35          20.0
3     3     30          30.0
4     4     40          30.0
5     5     40          20.0
6     6     60           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will test this solution and read more about some of the functions that you are using here that I'm not very familiar with. I will comeback with some feedback later today

Comment: I just marked it as the solution. I took some time to breakdown and understand all the code. I'm amazed on how you thought about this, thanks again for taking the time to help me out